# send POST data with cURL and execute with php header location

Tags: php, redirect, curl

timerecording.php needs the two values `$_POST['$currentyear']` and `$_POST['$currentmonth']`
to execute some code. This all is working fine when I make on "edit.php" a form with to hidden inputs which send the 2 values to the "timerecording.php" page.

But I run into trouble because I want to call `header('Location: ' . $url);` to redirect after a special funciton inside "edit.php" and to get the same result like I do the solution with the form inputs.

If I want to access the "edit.php" file over the web-browser - the side loads and loads till time out. But I don't receive any errors.

Here is the code from "edit.php":

```
$currentyear = 2013;
$currentmonth = 10;

$datatopost = array (
"year" => $currentyear,
"month" => $currentmonth
);


$url = "timerecording.php";

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $datatopost);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$url = curl_getinfo($ch , CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
header('Location: ' . $url);
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

what *curl_getinfo* returning ???

this problem happens when same page reloaded multipal times  due to `header('Location: ' . $url);` if url pointing to same web resource .